# Inserting procedure - value in an interval

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need help with the following:

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE LOG_PUSH_READOUTS_HEADERS

(

ID NUMBER NOT NULL,

PUSH_DATE DATE NOT NULL,

SOURCE_SERIAL VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

SOURCE_START_DATE DATE NOT NULL,

SOURCE_END_DATE DATE NOT NULL,

SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID NUMBER,

OUTPUT_SERIAL VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,

FILTERS_RUS VARCHAR2(100),

FILTERS_INDICATORS VARCHAR2(100),

CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID)

);
```

I need to implement the following procedure:

Input parameters for inserting in a table are all columns except ID for which we need to create a sequencer. Output parameters are ID and RESULT_CODE. ID is a value of primary key that is inserted. RESULT_CODE is zero if procedure is successful, or some value in an interval 9000-9999. Use RESULT_CODE for errors, for example, RESULT_CODE 9123 is 'FILTER_RUS cannot be null.'

Here is my attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_HEADER
(PUSH_DATE IN DATE, SOURCE_SERIAL IN VARCHAR2, SOURCE_START_DATE IN DATE, SOURCE_END_DATE IN DATE, SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID IN NUMBER, 
OUTPUT_SERIAL IN VARCHAR2, FILTERS_RUS IN VARCHAR2, FILTERS_INDICATORS IN VARCHAR2, ID OUT NUMBER, RESULT_CODE OUT NUMBER)

IS
hd_seq NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT AMM_MDM.Header_Seq.NEXTVAL INTO hd_seq FROM DUAL;
ID:=hd_seq;
INSERT INTO AMM_MDM.LOG_PUSH_READOUTS_HEADERS (PUSH_DATE IN DATE, SOURCE_SERIAL IN VARCHAR2, SOURCE_START_DATE IN DATE, 
SOURCE_END_DATE IN DATE, SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID IN NUMBER, 
OUTPUT_SERIAL IN VARCHAR2, FILTERS_RUS IN VARCHAR2, FILTERS_INDICATORS IN VARCHAR2)
VALUES (PUSH_DATE, SOURCE_SERIAL, SOURCE_START_DATE, 
SOURCE_END_DATE, SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID, 
OUTPUT_SERIAL, FILTERS_RUS, FILTERS_INDICATORS)

END;
```

How to set RESULT_CODE in an interval 9000-9999? How to manage errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood the question, it would be like the following example. I shortened column list (didn't feel like tying that much), but you should be able to get the general idea.

```
create or replace procedure p_insert_header
  (p_push_date     in date,
   p_source_serial in varchar2,
   p_filter_rus    in varchar2,
   --
   p_id           out number,
   p_result_code  out number
  )
is
  l_id number;
begin
  -- check for errors
  if p_push_date is null then 
     p_result_code := 1234;
  elsif p_source_serial not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then
     p_result_code := 5532;
  elsif p_filter_rus is null then
     p_result_code := 9123;
  end if;

  -- if there are no errors, do insert
  if p_result_code is null then
     -- fetch sequence number
     p_id := header_seq.nextval;

     insert into log_push_readouts_headers
       (id, push_date, source_serial, filter_rus)
       values
       (p_id, p_push_date, p_source_serial, p_filter_rus);
  end if;
end;
```

At the end, once the procedure finishes, it'll return - as OUT parameters:

- ID:

  - some sequence number, if everything was OK
  - NULL, if it was not
- RESULT_CODE:

  - NULL, if everything was OK
  - error number, if it was not

Answer (score 0):

For user defined errors, Oracle permits negative integers in the range `-20000 .. -20999`. You need to remove data type declarations for the column list of the insert statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_HEADER(PUSH_DATE          IN DATE,
                                          SOURCE_SERIAL      IN VARCHAR2,
                                          SOURCE_START_DATE  IN DATE,
                                          SOURCE_END_DATE    IN DATE,
                                          SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID IN NUMBER,
                                          OUTPUT_SERIAL      IN VARCHAR2,
                                          FILTERS_RUS        IN VARCHAR2,
                                          FILTERS_INDICATORS IN VARCHAR2,
                                          ID                 OUT NUMBER,
                                          RESULT_CODE        OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO LOG_PUSH_READOUTS_HEADERS
    (ID,
     PUSH_DATE,
     SOURCE_SERIAL,
     SOURCE_START_DATE,
     SOURCE_END_DATE,
     SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID,
     OUTPUT_SERIAL,
     FILTERS_RUS,
     FILTERS_INDICATORS)
  VALUES
    (Header_Seq.NEXTVAL,
     PUSH_DATE,
     SOURCE_SERIAL,
     SOURCE_START_DATE,
     SOURCE_END_DATE,
     SOURCE_RUS_TYPE_ID,
     OUTPUT_SERIAL,
     FILTERS_RUS,
     FILTERS_INDICATORS);

  --Suppose some opertions performed and gave the RESULT_CODE value below
     RESULT_CODE := 20123;

  IF    RESULT_CODE = 20123 THEN raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'FILTER_RUS cannot be null'); 
--ELSIF RESULT_CODE = 20124 THEN raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'Some other message 1');
--ELSIF RESULT_CODE = 20125 THEN raise_application_error(-RESULT_CODE, 'Some other message 2');
  END IF;     
END;
```

In this case it hurls with the message : `FILTER_RUS cannot be null`